# Python Beginner - "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error

Below is the code I am typing in Jupyter notebook,

```
 from pandas import read_csv 
 from matplotlib import pyplot 
 series = read_csv('daily-minimum-temperatures.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
 resample = series.resample('M')
```

Sample Data:

[image]

I am getting below error:

**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'**

Please suggest what am I missing, check the detailed error below:

---

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-93b88286f0b9> in <module>
----> 1 resample = series.resample('M')

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base, on, level)
   8153                      axis=axis, kind=kind, loffset=loffset,
   8154                      convention=convention,
-> 8155                      base=base, key=on, level=level)
   8156         return _maybe_process_deprecations(r,
   8157                                            how=how,

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in resample(obj, kind, **kwds)
   1248     """
   1249     tg = TimeGrouper(**kwds)
-> 1250     return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
   1251 
   1252 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in _get_resampler(self, obj, kind)
   1358 
   1359         """
-> 1360         self._set_grouper(obj)
   1361 
   1362         ax = self.ax

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in _set_grouper(self, obj, sort)
    183         if (self.sort or sort) and not ax.is_monotonic:
    184             # use stable sort to support first, last, nth
--> 185             indexer = self.indexer = ax.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    186             ax = ax.take(indexer)
    187             obj = obj._take(indexer, axis=self.axis, is_copy=False)

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in argsort(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4338         if result is None:
   4339             result = np.array(self)
-> 4340         return result.argsort(*args, **kwargs)
   4341 
   4342     def get_value(self, series, key):

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please post the code itself?

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: Sample Data, being entered in .csv file. How do I format this to text, if I have to? Date Temp
1981-01-01 21
1981-01-02 18
1981-01-03 19
1981-01-04 15
1981-01-05 16
1981-01-06 16
1981-01-07 16
1981-01-08 17
1981-01-09 22
1981-01-10 20
1981-01-11 16
1981-01-12 13
1981-01-13 17
1981-01-14 22
1981-01-15 25
1981-01-16 21
1981-01-17 21
1981-01-18 25
1981-01-19 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `pd.resample` on data frames, you have to specify a date-time like column for the `on`- parameter, see example from the documentation. Here, it would be

```
df.resample('M', on='Date')
```

If 'Date' is the index, this is not necessary. Also, you have to convert your date column to datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot.